# Compactness of the minimal ideal of a compact Hausdorff polytopological semigroup

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, semigroups-and-monoids

A semigroup $X$ endowed with a topology is called

$\bullet$ a *topological semigroup*  if the semigroup operation $X\times X\to X$ is continuous;

$\bullet$ a *semitopological semigroup* if for every $a,b\in X^1=X\cup \{1\}$ the map $X\to X$, $x\mapsto axb$, is continuous;

$\bullet$ a *polytopological semigroup* if for every $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in X^1$ the map  $X\to X$, $x\mapsto a_0xa_1x\dots xa_n$, is continuous.

It is well-known that each compact Hausdorff semitopological semigroup $X$ contains an idempotent $e$ such that $eXe$ is a compact subgroup of $X$ and $XeX$ is the minimal ideal of $X$. The minimal ideal $XeX$ is compact if the semitopological semigroup $X$ is topological.

The book "Analysis on semigroups" of Berglund, Junghenn, Milnes contains Example 5.5 of a compact semitopological semigroup $S$ (homeomorphic to $[0,1]^3$) in which the minimal ideal coincides with the set $E(S)$ and is not closed in $S$.

However this compact semitopological semigroup $S$ is not polytopological as the map $S\to S$, $x\mapsto x^2$, is discontinuous (because of the nonclosedness of $E(S)$).
This example motivates

> **Problem:** Is the minimal ideal in every compact Hausdorff polytopological semigroup $X$ closed in $X$?